# mysql, joining 2 tables, and checking for 2 conditions

Tags: php, sql, mysql, join

**MySQL**

table1:

```
+--------+------+
| listid | type |
+--------+------+
|    1   |  a   |
+--------+------+
|    2   |  a   |
+--------+------+
|    3   |  b   |
+--------+------+
```

table2:

```
+----+--------+------+
| id | listid | code |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 |    1   |  ax  |
+----+--------+------+
|  2 |    1   |  bx  |
+----+--------+------+
|  3 |    2   |  ax  |
+----+--------+------+
|  4 |    2   |  bx  |
+----+--------+------+
|  5 |    2   |  cx  |
+----+--------+------+
|  6 |    3   |  ax  |
+----+--------+------+
|  7 |    3   |  bx  |
+----+--------+------+
```

**Task**

In one query, I want to check if:

1) in the table **table2** only "ax" & "bx" are listed as **code**

2) the type of the **listid** I get in 1) is "a" in the table **table1**

**PHP**

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT t1.listid FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2......");
$b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a);

if($b['listid'])
{
    echo $b['listid'];
}
else
{
    echo 'nothing found';
}
```

**Output**

```
listid = 1
```

listid = 2 is false, because "cx" is also included in **table2**

listid = 3 is false, because it has type "b" in **table1**

I hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  t1.listid
FROM    t1
WHERE   type = 'a'
        AND id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  listid
        FROM    t2
        WHERE   code NOT IN ('ax', 'bx')
        )
```

This will also match records from `t1` which have no corresponding records in `t2` at all.